# Why when i'm adding a space between the cubes on a grid the whole grid size is change?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The grid is 10x10

This is the original script before adding spaces:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GridGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject gridBlock;
    public int gridWidth = 10;
    public int gridHeight = 10;
    public List<Vector3> positions = new List<Vector3>();
    public List<GameObject> blocks = new List<GameObject>();

    private GameObject[] wallsParents = new GameObject[4];

    void Start()
    {
        wallsParents[0] = GameObject.Find("Top Wall");
        wallsParents[1] = GameObject.Find("Left Wall");
        wallsParents[2] = GameObject.Find("Right Wall");
        wallsParents[3] = GameObject.Find("Bottom Wall");

        GenerateGrid();
    }

    private void GenerateGrid()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < gridWidth; x++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < gridHeight; z++)
            {
                GameObject block = Instantiate(gridBlock, Vector3.zero, gridBlock.transform.rotation) as GameObject;
                block.transform.parent = transform;
                block.transform.tag = "Block";
                block.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 0.1f, 1);
                block.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(x, 0, z);
                block.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = new Color(241, 255, 0, 255);

                if (block.transform.localPosition.x == 0)//TOP
                {
                    positions.Add(block.transform.localPosition);
                    block.transform.parent = wallsParents[0].transform;
                    block.transform.name = "TopWall";
                }
                else if (block.transform.localPosition.z == 0)//LEFT
                {
                    positions.Add(block.transform.localPosition);
                    block.transform.parent = wallsParents[1].transform;
                    block.transform.name = "LeftWall";
                }
                else if (block.transform.localPosition.z == gridWidth - 1)//RIGHT
                {
                    positions.Add(block.transform.localPosition);
                    block.transform.parent = wallsParents[2].transform;
                    block.transform.name = "RightWall";
                }

                else if (block.transform.localPosition.x == gridHeight - 1)//BOTTOM
                {
                    positions.Add(block.transform.localPosition);
                    block.transform.parent = wallsParents[3].transform;
                    block.transform.name = "BottomWall";
                }

                blocks.Add(block);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the result: The 4 walls are in place:

[image: Grid]

Then i changed the line:

```
block.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(x, 0, z);
```

To

```
block.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(x * 1.5f, 0, z * 1.5f);
```

And now the result is that the 4 walls are in wrong positions:

[image: grid]

Do i need to multiply also the walls blocks too ?

But if i multiply all the blocks already by 1.5f then why the walls blocks are not changing the position too by 1.5f ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
block.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(x * 1.5f, 0, z * 1.5f);
```

this line will set `localPosition.x  = 1.5f * x` which would only affect right and bottom walls because, for the top and left walls have `x = 0` so multiplication won't affect.

You have to change your comparison to check index value instead of `localPosition` :

```
if (x == 0) //TOP

if (z == 0) //LEFT

if (z == gridHeight - 1) //RIGHT

if (x == gridWidth - 1) //BOTTOM
```

This will add the right blocks in walls independent of position.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I forgot to ask what about if the grid size is for example 8x7 ? Now it's 10x10 and it's working fine also with 12x12 but not with 7x8 or 9x3

Comment: The logic I have suggested should work regardless the size of the grid. _Not working_ is banned from stackoverflow. You should explain your problem properly instead of saying that

Comment: Should i ask new question edit or explain here ? What i mean is that if for example the width is 7 and height is 8 the walls will not be in position like before.  This is what i mean when i click to highlight the grid https://imgur.com/a/CRqi7  and this is the walls when it's 7x8: https://imgur.com/a/rGKyr

Comment: can you share your latest code, maybe on pastebin.com or gist.github.com

Comment: Just realized Walls object is not at the origin (0,0,0). Could that be a problem?

Comment: Ahh my fault! if (z == gridHeight - 1) //RIGHT this was using gridWidth