# How can i use raycasthit to find what directions to move are available?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
var availableDirections = new Vector3[] { Vector3.forward, Vector3.left, Vector3.right, Vector3.back };
RaycastHit objectHit;
Vector3 fwd = player.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
Debug.DrawRay(player.transform.position, fwd * 1.5f, Color.green);
if (Physics.Raycast(player.transform.position, fwd, out objectHit, 1.5f))
{
    objectHit.transform.
}
```

I have array with all directions, i want only forward, left, right, backward
I don't want in this time to use diagonals.

When there is a hit, i want to find what direction from the player the laser of the raycast was hit. And then to set the right direction from the array to the hit direction.

Maybe i should also use a loop? If there are more then one possible directions i want to put all possible directions in a List. This way later i can tell the player what directions he can move to.

Right now i'm using Physics.OverlapBox but sometimes the player is facing outside the grid and that is not a possible direction to move to.

```
private void FindDirections()
{

    var availableDirections = new Vector3[] { Vector3.forward, Vector3.left, Vector3.right }

    .Select(directions => transform.position + directions * 1.5f)
    .Where(spot => Physics.OverlapBox(spot, Vector3.one * 0.5f).Length > 0)
    .ToArray();

    var direction = availableDirections[Random.Range(0, availableDirections.Length - 1)];

    player.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(start.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(direction), Time.deltaTime);
    player.forward = direction;

    if (Physics.OverlapBox(transform.position, Vector3.one * 0.5f)
.FirstOrDefault(collider => collider.gameObject.tag == "End")
 != null)
    {

    }        
}
```

The directions array was before that:

```
var availableDirections = new Vector3[]{Vector3.forward, Vector3.left, -Vector3.left}
```

In most cases there will be 3 directions possible or two.
So the array contain 3 directions.

But when running the game sometimes the player is facing outside:

[image: outside]

Comment: Again, you have a grid. Determine if the given direction results in a location that is outside the boundary of the grid.

Comment: @Draco18s First if i'm using raycast or OverlapBox then why when it's picking one direction it's facing outside the grid bound at first time ? It should facing only direction/s that raycast or OverlapBox detected cubes there no ? Second how can i check or tell when he is facing a direction that is out bound of the grid ? I didn't understand how do i know and check when he is facing outside the grid bound.

Comment: Do you, or do you not, have a `Grid` array somewhere? Like the one from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47576204/1663383)? Raycasts are pretty much the wrong tool here.

Comment: @Draco18s I have a grid array. This is my code: https://pastebin.com/jcuwpE2F the variable blocksArray contain all the grid cubes.  In the FixedUpdate i'm using raycast to find if there is a cube on any of the sides.  But you said that it's wrong to use raycast in this case. What should i do then ? I want to find what directions can i move to then rotate the player to randomly selected direction and then on the selected direction to select random cube as next waypoint to move to. This way until the player will get to end.

Comment: Take the player's position on the grid, find the next space in each desired direction, compare to the grid boundaries.

Comment: @Draco18s I'm still can't figure out how do you find the possible directions on the closest cubes.  Let's say i'm checking the right direction, how do i know the next cube is the closest one and not on the fourth place for example ?  And why using raycast is wrong ?

Comment: @Draco18s This is a working code i'm using now. It does what i wanted. Checking if there is any object in one of the directions add them to a list then take one random direction and rotate the player facing to this direction. https://pastebin.com/jsQ4B4nx And if you could please show me maybe how to do it the way you said ?

Comment: @Draco18s Another problem let's say the player rotated to random direction for example to the right. Now i want to select random cube on this direction as next waypoint to move to. How do you do it without raycast ? How do you know how many cubes there are at this direction to select one ?

Comment: Stop asking about raycasts. Generating a ray from a transform's direction is trivial and again, the wrong tool. Again, use your grid map. Your player can only have four rotations, that value can be used to figure out which direction they're facing, you can then query your `Grid`